# Print value and next value of dict on same line during iteration

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to iterate through the keys of the dictionary "rooms" and show only two keys per line.

Current code: (Python 2.7)

```
rooms = {
"105": "Room",
"128": "Room",
"101": "Room",
"102": "Room",
"103": "Room",
"104": "Room"}

for room, nextroom in zip(rooms.keys(), rooms.keys()[1:]):
    print room, nextroom
```

Current output:

```
102 128
128 103
103 101
101 104
104 105
```

Goal output:

```
102 128
103 101
104 105
```

Comment: Hi JonMichael Book, welcome to Stackoverflow.
1) Is this in Python? The code looks like it is Python but I wanted to double check.
2) It is not very clear from the post above how to get the goal output. Can you  elaborate more on that?

Comment: Sorry! Yes, this is Python. I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: @Francis I am trying to iterate through the keys of the dictionary "rooms" and show only two values per line.

Comment: Try `for room, nextroom in 
 zip(rooms.keys()[::2], rooms.keys()[1::2])` and check out [Understanding python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **iter**:

```
keys = iter(rooms.keys())
for key in keys:
    print key, next(keys)
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you cast the keys to a list, it's just a matter of walking through that list and grabbing them in batches of two. In Python 2 you can use `xrange` along with the following arguments to get the intended effect:

```
room_keys = rooms.keys()

for i in xrange(0, len(rooms), 2): 
  print room_keys[i], room_keys[i + 1]
```