# Print value and next value of dict on same line during iteration with an odd number of items

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, iteration

(Python 2.7) In my previous question, I was trying to iterate through the keys of the dictionary "rooms" and show only two keys per line, how can I go about showing an odd number of rooms at a time? More specifically, two per line until only one is left and only that one will go on a line on its own.

[Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53037823/print-value-and-next-value-of-dict-on-same-line-during-iteration)

Current Code:

```
rooms = {
"101": "Classroom",
"102": "Bathroom",
"103": "Room",
"104": "Room",
"105": "Room",
"106": "Room"}


keys = iter(sorted(rooms.keys()))
for key in keys:
    print key + "    " + next(keys)
```

Current Output:

```
101    102
103    104
105    106
```

Goal Output:

```
101    102
103    104
105    106
107
```

Comment: How's that possible if you have an even number of keys (like you do in your example dictionary)?

Answer (score 1):

[`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#next) takes an optional second argument for a default value to return when the iterator is exhausted.

```
keys = iter(sorted(rooms.keys()))
for key in keys:
    print key + "    " + next(keys, "")
```

Comment: I'd suggest "" though

Answer (score 0):

```
rooms = {
"101": "Classroom",
"102": "Bathroom",
"103": "Room",
"104": "Room",
"105": "Room",
"106": "Room",
"107": "Room"}


keys = iter(sorted(rooms.keys()))
for key in keys:
    try:
        print(key + "    " + next(keys))
    except StopIteration:
        print(key)
```

Though it might be a lot simpler to make `keys` a list and just check if you've reached the end.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively use `enumerate`.

```
from __future__ import print_function

per_line = 2
keys = iter(sorted(rooms.keys()))
for i, key in enumerate(keys):
    if (i + 1) % per_line == 0 or (i + 1) == len(rooms.keys()):
        print(key)
    else:
        print(key, end="\t")
```